# Reverse order of two list at the same time with same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two identical  `<ul>` list ,I need to reverse the order of the two list  using jQuery when i press a button.I have tried the bellow code and it is not working as expected.

```js
function spin(){
  spinList($('.list-view'));
}

var spinList       = function($el){
       
         var elementClone =  $el.eq(0).clone();
         var allLength    =  elementClone.find('li').length;
         for(var i = 0;i<allLength;i++){
            var element = elementClone.find('li').eq(allLength-i).clone();
            $el.eq(0).find('li').eq(i).replaceWith(element);
            $el.eq(1).find('li').eq(i).replaceWith(element);
         }  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="spin()">Change order</button>

<ul class="list-view">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="list-view">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use native JavaScript **[`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)** method

```js
function spin() {
  spinList($('.list-view'));
}

var spinList = function($el) {
  $el.each(function() { // iterate over the list
    $(this).append( // appending to change the order
      $('li', this) // get the li element
      .get() // get them as array
      .reverse() // reverse the order
    )
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="spin()">Click</button>

<ul class="list-view">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-view">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks !,This is fine:)

Comment: @ShijinTR : glad to help :)

Comment: You save my time,kill 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, with some ES6 features:

```js
function spin() {
  var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list-view');
  Array.from(lists).forEach((list) => {
    var reversed = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll('li')).reverse();
    list.innerHTML = '';
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    reversed.forEach((item) => {
   fragment.appendChild(item);    
    })
    list.appendChild(fragment);
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="spin()">Change order</button>

<ul class="list-view">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ul> 

<ul class="list-view">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ul>
```